# How do I calculate how "true" something STILL is? Weighted votes with the time they happened?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

Say I have a thing, and you can upvote/downvote it whether it's true. As time goes by, this thing changes, so I want votes that happened longer ago to matter less (at least, that's what I think should happen). Is there a formula for something like this? Am I missing something?

an idea:

`vote# is +1 if upvote, -1 if downvote`


`score = (vote1/time since vote1) + (vote2/time since vote2) + (vote3/time since vote3)`

That way score will increase with more votes and each individual vote starts decaying. High score would mean a lot of people upvoted that, and recently.

Comment: This sounds like something [prediction markets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_market) are designed to handle particularly well.

Comment: "Something like that" can work well. You'll probably want to fiddle with the divisor a bit so that it doesn't fall off quite as fast. For example, do you really want a vote from yesterday to be twice as relevant as a vote from two days ago? The suggestion of an exponential moving average is a good one, as is the idea of prediction markets (although they're a bit more involved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the most common approach is to use an *exponentially-weighted moving average*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average.

The nice thing with exponential weighting is that you only need to keep track of your current average, and then you can easily update it for each new incoming value, rather than needing to keep a full history of all past values in order to compute an updated average.

(Or at least, that's the case for weighting based on "number of data-points since this one". For weighting based on "amount of time since this data-point", where the data-points aren't at fixed intervals, it's *slightly* more complicated, because you'll also need to keep the timestamp of the last data-point; but you still don't need to keep the full history, so it's still very simple and efficient.)